# Why does Intellij IDEA suggest use 'List.of' to replace 'Collections.unmodifiableList' while I'm using java 8?

Tags: java, list, intellij-idea

I was using java 8 and here's my code:

```
final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<>();
descriptors.add(MY_PROPERTY);
this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);
```

But IDEA suggests to replace with 'List.of', which doesn't appear in java 8.
I was a little confused why IDEA suggests like that?
Any idea will be helpful and thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Note that you can replace _the entire code block_ with `List.of(MY_PROPERTY)`. It was added in Java 9 (Java 8's general LTS currency ended a couple of years ago).

Comment: Are you sure that Intellij IDEA shares your perception that you are writing Java 8 code? Check your IDEA setup and which code version you *really* use …

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- – Yeah, but `List.of()` was introduced with Java 9 … – So when Victor.Li is really using Java 8, that call is invalid in his code …

Comment: Having the project settings set to Java 9 might cause IntelliJ to use the Java 9 migration inspections.

Answer (score 3):

Your complaint seems to be that IntelliJ is suggesting the use of features available in Java 9 and later but you want to build only for Java 8.

## Set *Project language level* to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`

There are multiple places within a project in IntelliJ where you must set the specific version of Java to be considered or used. Unfortunately, you have to poke around with each of them manually as IntelliJ lacks any kind of general "set my project to Java version x" feature.

➥ After some experimenting, I found I could provoke a situation like yours by setting *File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project > Project language level* to `9 - Modules, private methods in interfaces etc.`.

I suggest checking that setting. Verify `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`.

[image: File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Project > Project language level]

---

Also, notice above that setting the `Project SDK` setting. That should be set to a JDK for Java 8.

---

And check *File > ProjectStructure > ProjectSettings > Modules -> sources > Language level* is set to `8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.`.

---

Yet another place to check is *Preferences/Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler*:

- *Project bytecode version* should be set to *Same as language level*.
- *Per-module bytecode version* should have *Target bytecode version* set to `8`.

---

If using Apache Maven as your dependency manager and build configurator, set these elements in your POM to `8`:

```xml
<maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
```

In later versions of Maven tooling, the two elements above may be replaced by this single element:

```xml
<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
```

Comment: Good answer! I saw unnecessary left-indentation with your code block which I fixed but I also wondered if there is any advantage of formatting a code block using ```xml...```. How is it different from formatting the code block using the `{ }` tool in the editor?

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I notice that my 'Project Language Level' is 8, but 'Target Bytecode Version' is 11. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue with Intellij IDEA 2021.1. It suggests to use `List.of` when the language level is 9 or higher and it doesn't when the language level is 8.

You're probably using a higher language level than 8 in either the project settings or the module settings. Both need to be set to Java 8. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-modules.html) post for how to set up the language level in Intellij.